# How convert blob type in to data url using spring MVC?

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, blob

I'm creating a Spring MVC application. I also have a dataTable in the MySQL database. Inside the database, there is a table, and inside the table consist of several columns. One of the columns has type data "LONGBLOB" (the name of the column is file_data)

[image]

The picture is the content of 1 "file_data".
1. How to convert the file_data which has longblob type to data URL?

There are some tutorials/discussions about this topic on the internet, but mostly using javascript. I have not got the idea how to convert it by using spring MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can use javascript to the blob data. The idea is, try to show the data from your controller into your html/jsp file (frontend). And then, try to get the content, for example you put the data inside tag `div` with certain `class` or `id`.

After that, try to get it inside javascript, for example `var blob = document.getElementById('<you id/class name>').innerHTML;`
`var data = new Blob([blob], {type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'});
URLdata = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);`